# Moto X: Press 1 to Accept Incoming Call

Tags: moto-x

Recently, upon receiving an incoming call, I get a voice notification asking me to "Press 1 to answer the call".  Probably started a couple of days ago, which perhaps correlates to having received Motorola Assist updates about that time.

My initial thought was that this was Google Voice call screening.  While I do have GV installed, I am not using it nor have I even set it up.

Any thoughts on where else the calls are getting trapped out?

Comment: Are you still able to receive the incoming call? Or does it get blocked out of the system, following an auto disconnect?

Comment: Yes, I can answer the call by pressing "1".

Comment: That is most certainly very odd. Have you tried talking to your network operator about the same? I feel it's quite unlikely that an app is allowed to intervene with your calls in such a manner.

Comment: Yes, began all of a sudden.  I uninstalled GV just to be certain it wasn't GV intercepting.  No other recent installations of note.  I'll call VZW.

Comment: ah-ha!  I have been using a Google voice number to forward to my cell.  Somehow and for some reason, GV's call screen setting was enabled.  Uncertain how this occurred, as I haven't logged into the GV account in quite some time since initial setup.  Problem solved.

Comment: I see. LOVELY! Why don't you answer your own question with a solution for other people and then the mods can mark this as closed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem was to turn off Google Voice Call Screening. Though the GV app was not installed and I do not know how the setting became enabled, I logged onto my GV account to turn off this setting.